# Pronunication of "Dijkstra"

Tags: pronunciation, proper-nouns

I am a computer professional. I have heard the pronuciation of the word *Dijkstra* from various sources as

1. *di-kstra*
2. *diji-kstra*
3. *dik-stra*

Which is the correct way of pronouncing it?

Comment: This has been answered adequately elsewhere at [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4381/pronunciation-dijkstra) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra)

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. Not one of the links given above has an IPA pronunciation of "Dijkstra" for English.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Edsger Wybe Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) was a Dutch computer scientist. The Dutch pronunciation of his name is given as  `ˈɛtsxər ˈwibə ˈdɛɪkstra`. You can listen to it [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Dijkstra.ogg) and [here (this one is more clear)](http://howjsay.com/index.php?word=dijkstra&submit=Submit).

Comment: ...but the one from Howjsay is less correct. Forvo has several clear and correct ones: http://www.forvo.com/search/dijkstra/nl/

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica In some of the examples on forvo I hear "day-kstra" while in others I here "die-kstra". How come?

Comment: @NPS: To me, as a native speaker, all those ij's sound correct and more or less the same. None sound like *day* or *die* to me, but that is probably how your mind categorises the ij sound if you're unfamiliar with it. There may be very slight (to me) variations that make your mind put them in one or the other category familiar to you? I think the IPA /ɛɪ/ is probably the best rendering of the sound. Foreigners often find diphthongs like ij/ei, eu, and ui very difficult to master or even recognise...

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Thank you for that comment. So I guess this sound is inbetween those. Kinda like `a` in `back` (not really `a`, not really `e`, something inbetween).

Comment: @NPS: I suppose you could say that! Fun fact: there are plenty of Dutch accents in which ij/ei is pronounced like in English *die* (especially northern and lower-class accents). In some southern, lower-class The Hague, and Flemish accents, it may sound more like è (IPA /ɛː/).

Answer (score 10):

In English, the Dutch name Dijkstra is normally pronounced DYKE-struh, in IPA /ˈdɑɪkstɹə/.

Answer (score 6):

It is a Dutch name, where the 'j' is always silent or pronounced like a 'y'. So the name should be 'dyk(bike, hike in English) -stra'.